# error Operator '>' is not defined for types 'User' and 'Integer' and Value of type 'User' cannot be converted to 'Integer'

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, label

I have an error error Operator '>' is not defined for types 'User' and 'Integer' and Value of type 'User' cannot be converted to 'Integer'.

is there something wrong in my code?

Thanks

```
   Dim userid = uService.GetUserById(CInt(lblid.Text))
                If userid > 0 Then 'this line error 
                    End If


Public Function GetUserById(ByVal UserNo As Integer) As User
            Dim sql = $"SELECT  * FROM Users WHERE id = {UserNo}"
            Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(DbContext.GetOledbConnectionString())
                Return _conn.Query(Of User)(sql).FirstOrDefault()
            End Using
        End Function
```

Comment: The method declaration specifically states that it is returning a `User` object. Why would you expect to be able to compare that to an `Integer` in any meaningful way? You seem to think that that method is actually returning the `UserNo` of that `User`, even though that would be the same value that you just passed in to it. You seem not to have even read the code you just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetUserById` returns a user, if this user exists, and `Nothing` otherwise (because of `.FirstOrDefault()`).

Instead of checking the result for a user id > 0, check the result for `Nothing`

```vb
Dim user = uService.GetUserById(CInt(lblid.Text))
If user IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Do something with user
End If
```

A safer way to do this is to check whether the user input is a valid integer:

```vb
Dim userId As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(lblid.Text, userId) Then
    Dim user = uService.GetUserById(userId)
    If user IsNot Nothing Then
        ' Do something with user
    End If
End If
```